# Best way to achieve SSL pinning for native apps using azure api management

Tags: ios, azure, ssl, azure-api-management

I need to prevent MIM(Man in the middle attack) for my native apps which use Azure API management. Though we have secured API management using JWT, we need to secure the HTTPS requests coming from apps to prevent a man in the middle attack. What is the best way to achieve SSL pinning using Azure API management?

I tried adding a self signed SSL certificate in API management certificate, but the apps are not able to use that certificate. What would be the best way to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Using a certificate signed by a public CA is really your only option for a publicly accessible endpoint. You could use a private CA if you're in an enterprise environment with the CA trusted on all devices connecting to the endpoint.